# SQL Server stored procedure syntax to return retval from execute passing job name to sp_stop_job

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, syntax, sql-agent

I have a poor SQL Server experience but, having to maintain an old (very old) SQL Server instance, I'm currently trying to write a complex stored procedure but it's failing (due to syntax) when I try, eg, to stop a job.

So, I am now struggling to find a working syntax to:

- execute msdb.sp_stop.job
- passing it a job name which I've stored into a @job_name variable
- returning a (declared) @retval variable to later understand if the job actually stopped or not.

I am trying some syntax variations (all failing for some reason), and I guess my poor experience needs help, hints. I tried to spot from some other default procedures, too (like `sp_help_job`)

Here is my last test try:

```
GO
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE my_test_stop_job
    -- Individual job parameters
    @job_name                   sysname          = NULL  -- If provided should NOT also provide job_id

AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @retval          INT

    -- Remove any leading/trailing spaces from parameters (except @owner_login_name)
    SELECT @job_name         = LTRIM(RTRIM(@job_name))

    -- Turn [nullable] empty string parameters into NULLs
    IF (@job_name         = N'') SELECT @job_name = NULL

    IF (@job_name IS NOT NULL)      
        BEGIN       
            EXECUTE ('@retval = EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job @job_name = ''' + @job_name + '''')

                    IF (@retval <> 0)
                            RETURN(1) -- Failure                        
                        ELSE                
                            RETURN(0) -- status OK

        END

END

GO
```

which, launched using

```
EXEC mydb.dbo.my_test_stop_job @job_name = 'jobname2bestopped'
```

fails giving:

```
must declare the variable '@retval'
```

How can this be done? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for dynamic-SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_test_stop_job
    -- Individual job parameters
    @job_name                   sysname          = NULL  
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @retval          INT;

    -- Remove any leading/trailing spaces from parameters 
    SELECT @job_name         = LTRIM(RTRIM(@job_name));

    -- Turn [nullable] empty string parameters into NULLs
    IF (@job_name         = N'') SELECT @job_name = NULL;

    IF (@job_name IS NOT NULL)      
    BEGIN       
        EXECUTE @retval =  msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job @job_name = @job_name;

        IF (@retval <> 0)
            RETURN(1); -- Failure                        
        ELSE                
            RETURN(0); -- status OK
    END
END   
GO
```

Also I suggest to `THROW` exception when job name is `NULL` otherwise your stored procedure will exit with code `0`.

---

If from some reason you need dynamic-SQL, you could use `EXEC dbo.sp_executesql` with `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: That form was more like my first variant, but there I tried to compose the "@job_name = @job_name" with string/variable concatenation (using + and string delimiters)... I'll try asap what you suggest above... about throw, that is only a test, the whole procedure handles this retval better.. thanks.

Comment: @m.ardito You should do concatenation/other text operation before execution and just pass variable name `EXEC procedure @job_name = @job_name`

Comment: ok, I tried and that works... before I guessed the procedure needed something special to distinguish the two "@job_name" meanings... so I was trying to concatenate both with quotes... thanks.